# Unable to ping server from client B but able to ping from client A. Please help

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

This is not really a programming question, but I am at my wit's end ...

I am trying to configure a IIS 6.0/Windows Server 2003 web server with a ASP.net application.

When I try to ping the server from client computer A I get the following:

```
PING 74.208.192.xxx ==> Ping fails
PING 74.208.192.xxx:80 ==> Ping succeeds!
```

From client computer B, BOTH the pings fail.

```
    PING 74.208.192.xxx ==> Ping fails
    PING 74.208.192.xxx:80 ==> Ping fails with a message 
"Ping request could not find host 74.208.192.xxx:80"
```

Both clients A and B are on the same subnet. The server is outside (a virtual server hosted by an ISP)

I have an ASP.NET application in a virtual directory on the server. In IE or firefox, if I enter `http://74.208.192.xxx/subdir/subdir/../Default.aspx,` it works from both the clients!

The server has default firewall settings but web server enabled (Port 80 is open).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this better suited for [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com)?

As long as the web app is working fine, why are you "at your wit's end" over ping? Why do you need it?

You don't "ping" a port; ports are abstractions in TCP and UDP, but not present in ICMP, the protocol used by ping; so I have no idea how PING 74.208.192.xxx:80 "succeeds". Could you post a text log of what you see on-screen?

Check to see if the server is blocking ICMP, you'll have to fiddle with firewall settings in Windows to check this.

Also, make sure you can ping from both computers (A and B) to an external, known-good host (I recommend pinging yahoo.com) to see if a local firewall isn't blocking your pings.

Comment: From client A (ping failure)
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>ping 74.208.192.xx

Pinging 74.208.192.xx with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 74.208.192.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: From client A(ping success- note the different 'reply from' address)
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>ping 74.208.192.xx:80

Pinging 74.208.192.xx:80 [208.67.216.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 208.67.216.xxx: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=54
...
...
Reply from 208.67.216.xxx: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 208.67.216.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 32ms, Maximum = 54ms, Average = 38ms

Comment: From client B(both pings fail)
----------
C:\Documents and Settings\user>ping 74.208.192.81

Pinging 74.208.192.81 with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
...
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 74.208.192.81:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Documents and Settings\user>ping 74.208.192.81:80
Ping request could not find host 74.208.192.81:80. Please check the name and try
 again.

Comment: My main problem is I have a web service (asmx) file and the web service client program is not able to access it from client B, but able to access it from client A. I am trying to find out why and thought this ping issue may shed some light.

Comment: Yes, I can ping yahoo.com both the computers.

Comment: I moved this question to serverfault.
http://serverfault.com/questions/145678/client-a-can-ping-server-s-but-client-b-cannot